# Не работает лямбда выражение в Collectors.toMap()

Tags: java, map, lambda, java-stream, лямбда-выражение

Пытаюсь собрать мапу с помощью стрима, падает ClassCastException. В общем, есть класс Person:

```
public class Person{
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public Person (String name, int ;){
        this.name= name;
        this.age= age;
    }
```

Мне нужно создать Map с помощью stream, и объекты там должны быть отсортированы по возрасту. Я пишу:

```
Person person1 = new Person("b", 1);
Person person2 = new Person("c", 2);
Person person3 = new Person("a", 3);

List<Person > personList = new ArrayList<>();
personList.add(person1);
personList.add(person2);
personList.add(person3);

Map<String, Person> map = personList.stream()
                .sorted().collect(Collectors.toMap((o -> o.getName()), o -> o));
```

У меня падает ClassCastException. Не могу понять как должно выглядеть лямбда выражение внутри toMap().
И еще вопрос, как указать методу sorted сравнивать объекты именно по возрасту, у меня получалось только по имени, я использовал compareTo(), но int - примитив и тут этот вариант не работает.

Буду благодарен за любую помощь.

Comment: только не понятно зачем сортировка, если потом это попадает в мапу

Comment: @Stranger вы правы, до меня сейчас дошло, что я не правильно понял суть поставленной задачи. В мапу должен попасть только один объект Person, у которого будет самый большой age.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, классу `Person` нужны геттеры

```
class Person {
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public Person (String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
}
```

Во-вторых, методу `sorted` нужен компаратор, который будет сравнивать элементы

```
Map<String, Person> map = personList.stream()
  .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(Person::getAge))
  .collect(Collectors.toMap(Person::getName, Function.identity()));
```

А чтобы гарантировать сохранение упорядоченности элементов в результирующей коллекции, стоит явно указать её реализацию:

```
.collect(Collectors.toMap(Person::getName,
                          Function.identity(),
                          (a, b) -> a,
                          LinkedHashMap::new));
```

**UPD:** Чтобы собрать в `Map` один элемент с самым большим возрастом

```
Map<String, Person> map = personList.stream()
  .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(Person::getAge).reversed())
  .limit(1)
  .collect(Collectors.toMap(Person::getName, Function.identity()));
```

Но тогда непонятно, зачем нужен `Map` для одного элемента. Можно просто

```
Person person = personList.stream()
                          .max(Comparator.comparingInt(Person::getAge))
                          .get();
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, только я Вас немного запутал. До меня дошло, что в мапу должен попасть только один объект Person, у которого будет самый большой age

Comment: @Artem дополнил ответ.